# Redirect Apache Tomcat console log to Intellij (output tab)

Tags: tomcat, logging, intellij-idea, tomcat8

When I run tomcat(8) (using startup.bat), All the logs are shown in the console. I want to have all these logs in the output tab as shown in the following picture.

[image: intellij log tab]

When I start tomcat (with catalina.bat) I can redirect all the logs to a single file:

```
catalina.bat run 1>logFile.log 2>&1
```

But when I want to do the same thing in IntelliJ as follow:

[image]

The logFile is not generated. I wanted to use the logFile.log to add it as a log entry in intelliJ. Isn't there any simple answer to my question. I guess tomcat is good for nothing :(

Answer (score 1):

Use **Save console output to file** option in the **Logs** tab of your Run/Debug Configuration:

[image]

Comment: no, the problem is that when I start tomcat, using startup.bat, I get a full log on the console, but when I run it in tomcat I can't get all the logs. I did not have this problem with the (beloved) JBoss. that is why I tried all these approaches, (to get a full log in tomcat)